# Perl Dancer Template headers, footers

Tags: perl, templates, template-toolkit, dancer

I'm learning Perl and using Dancer as a web framework. 
I've got two views (tt files) which should share the same navigation.
So, it would be great to start learning how to manage templates for navigation and footers.

I've read the documentation for the Template Toolkit and I've done the following:

I've changed the `config.yml` file to:

```
#template: "simple"

template: "template_toolkit"
engines:
     template_toolkit:
     start_tag: '[%'
     end_tag:   '%]'
```

I've defined the templates in the `.pm` file:

```
package proyecto;
use Dancer ':syntax';

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {
    template 'index';
};


get '/menu' => sub {
    template 'menu';
};

true;
```

There is a link in the index template directing the visitor to the menu template:

```
<li class="active">< a href="/menu">Menu <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
```

I would like to reuse the navigation code from index.tt into menu.tt, so I've wrapped the navigation code in index.tt with the following:

```
[% BLOCK navigation %]
#my nav code
[% END %]
```

To finally include that code in the menu.tt file, I've written the following (where the navigation code should be):

```
[% navigation = 'index.tt' %]
[% INCLUDE navigation %]
```

The files `index.tt` and `menu.tt` are located in the folder views. But it seems it's not that easy! =( Any suggestion on how to reuse code from one file to another which is located in the same directory?

Comment: Note: Package names in Perl start with capital letters by convention.

Comment: @This bet me because I got lost reading the documentation when I was looking for the link. :) Post an answer.

Comment: @simbabque I originally posted a Dancer2 link and changed it...had to dig a bit to find the Dancer1 version. So I guess I cheated?? ;-)

Comment: @This could be. But it's fine. Very good answer. :)

Comment: Unrelated, but your config file is wrong (YAML is whitespace sensitive, unfortunately): the `start_tag` and `end_tag` directives need to be indented more than the `template_toolkit` directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [layouts](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Introduction.pod#LAYOUTS) are for. The idea is that content common to all pages (e.g. header, footer, navbar) goes in the layout and content specific to each page goes in templates called [views](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Introduction.pod#VIEWS). Views are called "partials" in other frameworks because they only contain the content for *part* of the page.

If you use the `dancer` command line utility to set up your application, the default layout is `views/layouts/main.tt` and looks something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=<% settings.charset %>" />
  <title>Foo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<% request.uri_base %>/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <% content %>
  <div id="footer">
    Powered by <a href="http://perldancer.org/">Dancer</a> <% dancer_version %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<% content %>` section is replaced with the specified view when you call `template 'view';`. (In your case, you'll need to change `<%` and `%>` to `[%` and `%]` since you're using the Template Toolkit-style delimiters.)

For example, if `views/index.tt` is:

```
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

calling `template 'index';` in a route renders the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Foo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  <div id="footer">
    Powered by <a href="http://perldancer.org/">Dancer</a> 1.3202
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that there's already a footer section; you just have to add elements for a header and navbar.

If this is new development, you should really be using [Dancer2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2) instead of Dancer (fortunately, layouts and views are the same in both).

Answer (score 3):

The `[% INCLUDE %]` directive's argument can be interpreted in one of two ways.

1. The name of another template file
2. The name of a block that is defined in the current template file (or in another template file which has included the current template file).

All of which means that your current plan won't work. `menu.tt` won't see any block defined inside `index.tt`.

There are a couple of better solutions though.

Firstly, consider moving the navigation code into a third, separate, template file. You can then `INCLUDE` this template into both `index.tt` and `menu.tt`.

Secondly, you can use Dancer's "layout" feature. This is a template that is wrapped around your view templates. Typically the layout template contains the navigation and all standard page furniture (like headers and footers). It also contains a `[% content %]` directive. When a view is rendered, the rendered version is dropped into the layout template in the location of the `[% content %]` directive. See the [Layouts](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Tutorial.pod#Layouts) section in [Dancer::Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Tutorial) for more information.

p.s. I see you're using Dancer. I'd highly recommend switching to Dancer2.

Comment: It's not yet clear whether OP is using Dancer or Dancer2.

Comment: I don't think that matters. There's no difference between the handling of layouts in the two versions, is there?

Comment: @simbabque: There's `use Dancer ':syntax';` which clearly shows Dancer 1.

Comment: @choroba right, I overread it. In that case, the documentation link is https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Tutorial.pod#Layouts. But I agree that there is no difference for the concept. But a link to D2 docs might confuse readers.

Comment: Updated to use Dancer links.

Comment: I love the last line. :)